# How do I copy a Firebase project? (Noob)

Tags: firebase

I am new to Firebase and GitHub and I need some help. I have downloaded a Firebase project template from GitHub which I want to copy (in order to learn). [This](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-web) is the project.

What I want is to create a web page like the one in that project (I want to copy it), but I do not understand what I need to do in order to reproduce the Firebase settings behind that page. I followed the instructions in the GitHub link, but it seems as if there are some steps missing which might be obvious for a Firebase expert but I do not know. For example, can't I simply copy the files from GitHub and paste them in my Firebase project? I am a bit lost.

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I do not know any other better site. What I want is to create a Firebase project with the same configuration as the one from GitHub: is this possible? If so, could anyone please explain me what needs to be done? I am not asking you to make the work for me, nor do I ask you to make a tutorial for me, I only need some hints and the general idea which I need to follow. If I knew what needs to be done, I could search more information in the internet, but now I am clueless. I already looked up for tutorials, but I was not able to find any tutorial on "how to copy a Firebase template for noobs".

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

PS: If anybody doubts whether this project is too ambitious to start with without having any previous knowledge, you need to know that my final goal is pretty similar to this project and I could spare maany hours if I copy this template and then do the canges I need to do (with some internet research).

Comment: Did you do "Create and configure your Firebase Project" section in the github readme? More precely step 2,3,4 ?

when you run "npm run serve" does it throw errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

It's great that you found an example app that is close to what you want to accomplish. That can indeed save you much time in building your own app.

But downloading an example app is typically not a great learning experience. To learn more about how Firebase works in an app, I recommend taking the [Firebase codelab for web developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/) and the follow-up [codelab for Cloud Functions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/). A few hours spent on those, will also save you many more hours down the line.

After that, follow the steps in [create and configure your Firebase Project](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-web#create-and-configure-your-firebase-project) and either [start a local development server](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-web#create-and-configure-your-firebase-project) or [deploy the app](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-web#deploy-the-app).